# Constraint issue with iPad using single storyboard iOS

Tags: ios, grid, storyboard, autolayout, constraints

I am having issues with a specific view on my storyboard. The button and textview don't show in the right place when using the ipad. It works perfect for the iPhone, however. I am using one storyboard for the both of them. (Not one each) Here is a screenshot for what it is showing and the blue rect is for where the textview should be and the red is for where the GPS button, which is visible to the left, should show. Any ideas? I have tried setting and reseting the constraints, but it has had zero effect.

Thanks[image]

Comment: Could you show us your storyboard or code that you use to lay out this view?

Comment: I got it figured out awhile ago. Thanks